# Going to make my first pizza tonight, can a large, thick griddle pan substitute for a pizza stone?

Tags: equipment, pizza, cast-iron

Going to make my first homemade pizza tonight, but I do not have a pizza stone.  Would a large (9" x 16" x 1/2") cast iron griddle work in place of a pizza stone?  The griddle is super black and well seasoned.  I also have a new oven, that will be broken in tonight.

I have some dough from a local pizza joint, and all the ingredients for a pepperoni pizza.  Any help/advice would be great.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What style of pizza are you aiming at?

Comment: Just a thin crust pepperoni pizza, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 5):

It should work just fine.  Preheat your oven, with the griddle inside, for at least an hour.  Build your pizza on a peel that has been sprinkled with some cornmeal so that it slides off.  If you don't have a peel, use the back of a sheet pan and some parchment paper underneath.  Then slide the pizza and parchment onto your griddle.

If you have a new oven, you may need to go through a preheat/burn-off without food first...check your manual.

Comment: Thanks.  Going to warm up the griddle on the stove first, then preheat the oven.  I have already cleaned the oven and read the manual.